# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'undefined'

Tags: angular

html code

```
<div class="section-layout text-center">
                <a [routerLink]="[pricing]" class="btn btn-primary my-5">Upgrade</a>
            </div>
```

hi ,when i try to login and its this upgrade button its navigating me to (https://dev.socialtools.me/Plans-and-Pricing-Application-on-Facebook) this url and letter if i refresh the page and try to click on this button its giving me an error

Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'undefined' https://dev.socialtools.me/undefined)

Comment: `pricing` is a variable. Do you want to use the variable or route to `/pricing`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming pricing is route not variable

```
[routerLink]="[/'pricing']"
```